# Match all newlines between two tags

Tags: regex

In a string that represents html markup, I need to remove all newlines that are between any `<ul></ul>`. Here is an example string:

`<ul>\n<li>element 1\n</li>\n<li>element 2\n</li>\n</ul><p>Hello there</p>`.

So all the `\n` inside the `<ul></ul>` need to be removed.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working correctly:

https://regex101.com/r/qLxSys/1

`/<ul>.*?(\n)?.*?<\/ul>/`

Can anybody please help me understand how I'd accomplish my goal?

Comment: You should try double substitution. First match with `(?<=<ul>).*(?=<\/ul>)`. Then replace`\n`. Finally replace the match with the clean one.

Comment: Along with what @bulbus said, depending on your language, you maybe be able to pass a function to handle replacing the value in between the tags, and then remove the newlines inside that function.

Comment: hey did my solution (below) answered your question? didn't it? why? what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match newline between `<ul>` marks you can use: 
[`(?<=<ul>).*?(\n).*(?=<\/ul>)`](https://regex101.com/r/a80YU7/2/)

Group 1 only matches one `\n` character inside `<ul>`. 
So I propose you to replace the string iteratively by the non-matching substrings (i.e. for each `\n` replace by subtrings between `<ul>` and `\n` on the left; between `\n` and `<\ul>` on the right). This implementation depends on you programming language:

In Python3:

```
#!python3
import re
string = "<ul>\n<li>element 1\n</li>\n<li>element 2\n</li>\n</ul>\n<p>Hello there</p>"
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=<ul>)(.*?)(\n)(.*)(?=<\/ul>)(?su)')
while pattern.search(string):
    string = pattern.sub(r'\g<1>'+r'\g<3>', string)
print(string)
```

In the above example, the last `\n` is not replaced because it is not between `<ul>`.

Another cleaner solution is to use regex to match '\n' characters after using a html parser (eg. beautifulsoup in python) to get only the `<ul>` elements.